# error.org.jsonException.No value for "opening_hours"

Tags: android, json

I am trying to get object "opening_hours",However I am getting No value JSON Exception

This is my JSON

```
"results" : [
          {

             "icon":"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
             "id" : "9328c5d6999dcbfc82acb7ec63df4df9f917731e",
             "name" : "Tapas Restaurant",
             "opening_hours" : {
                "open_now" : true,
                "weekday_text" : []
             }
          }
         ,
          {

         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "10b0e9cea202572970aad34e9f252dac5e5220f8",
         "name" : "Laraib Inn",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : false,
            "weekday_text" : []
         }  
}
]
```

Here is my code to get JSON

```
var rootobject:JSONObject= JSONObject(response)
                    var objectarray:JSONArray=rootobject.getJSONArray("results")
                    for(i in 0..objectarray.length()-1){
                        var part:JSONObject=objectarray.getJSONObject(i)

                        var timepart:JSONObject=part.getJSONObject("opening_hours")
```

Comment: please add the entire JSON object

Comment: result is the array of different objects in this json thats why i m getting object

Comment: @NuOne T Attygalle   i didn't get it

Comment: this json object is incomplete.. can you add the full json string.,

Comment: I have added it

Comment: above json object is not a valid json object . you can validate json object here jsoneditoronline.org/ and then post the json object please

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to use GSON library (serialization/deserialization library to convert Java Objects into JSON and back) - https://github.com/google/gson

Then make object (wrapper) with following attributes (and embedded object with name "opening_hours" inside (named B in example)).

So object example:

`A {
icon (string),
id (string), 
name (string), 
    B { 
    open_now (boolean)
    weekday_text (array)
    ...
     }
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject object1= JSONObject(response);
JSONArray array1=object1.getJSONArray("results");
for(int i=0;i<array1.length();i++){
      JSONObject object2=array1.getJSONObject(i);
       JSONArray array1=object1.getJSONArray("opening_hours");
       Boolean open_now=array1.getString("open_now");
}
```

try it...